# How do I implement simple a RxJava call into a Runnable Thread?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm try to add a simple RxJava call into a runnable thread so I can update the UI once the thread is completed.  How do I go about doing that?  Here is my Activity code:

```
public class PrintActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_printer);
        printZpl("^XA^LL360^POI^FO20,20^A0N,25,25^FDThis is a test of the ZPL file printing on " + Helper.getCurrDateTime() + "^FS^XZ");
    }
}
```

Here is the class which performs the runnable thread:

```
public class PrinterManager {
    private static void printZpl(final String body, final String footer) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Connection btCon = new BluetoothConnectionInsecure("AC:3F:A4:0E:22:05");
                    btCon.open();
                    btCon.write(body.getBytes());
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    btCon.close();
                    // Insert RxJava return here to update the UI in the activity once the thread is completed.
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Timber.e(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I simplified the code for this posting.  The actual code is much, much more complex...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the asynchronous part of your code in an Observable like this:

```
public class PrinterManager {
    public static Observable<Void> printZpl(final String body, final String footer) {

    return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            try {
                Connection btCon = new BluetoothConnectionInsecure("AC:3F:A4:0E:22:05");
                btCon.open();
                btCon.write(body.getBytes());
                Thread.sleep(500);
                btCon.close();                  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Timber.e(e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Then, in your Activity, subscribe to it, triggering the code inside:

```
public class PrintActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_printer);
        PrinterManager.printZpl("^XA^LL360^POI^FO20,20^A0N,25,25^FDThis is a test of the ZPL file printing on " + Helper.getCurrDateTime() + "^FS^XZ")
                      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                      .subscribe();
    }
}
```

If you haven't already, you will need to add the dependencies to your `app.gradle` file:

```
compile "io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0"
compile "io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0"
```

If you want to update the UI, then pass an Observer to the `subscribe` method, instead of just using the empty one as in my example above.

Comment: I got it to work once I changed the return value to Observable<Void>. i.e.    public static Observable<Void> rxJavaPrint2 (final String body) {
        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                try {

Comment: @Jalsa true! Updated to with `return` statement and proper type.

Comment: How would I go about updating the UI with something like:  finishTextView.setText("Printing Completed"); ??  Sorry, I'm a newbie :-)

Comment: There are different version of the `subscribe()` method. One takes an `Observer` type. I would recommend implementing and `Observer`, and  there in its `onNext` or `onCompleted` you can write code to update the UI.

Comment: Just add a Disposable Observer into your subscribe() like this:

Comment: `PrinterManager2.rxJavaPrint2(podTest())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
            Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                // Update TextView
            }

            Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }
        });`

Answer (score 3):

Using RxJava2:

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> {
            Connection btCon = new BluetoothConnectionInsecure("AC:3F:A4:0E:22:05");
            btCon.open();
            btCon.write(body.getBytes());
            Thread.sleep(500);
            btCon.close();
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
```

Use a `Completable` instead of an `Observable` since you do not emit anything but the completion event.

Comment: When I try this code, I get an error: Lambda expressions are not supported at this language level